# UsbDevice.FromIdAsync returns null

Tags: c#, .net, usb, uwp, windows-10-universal

I have this code:

```
private async void OnDeviceAdded(DeviceWatcher watcher, DeviceInformation deviceInformation)
    {
        if (deviceInformation.Name.StartsWith("ClearShot") && deviceInformation.IsEnabled)
        {

            targetDevice = await UsbDevice.FromIdAsync(deviceInformation.Id);
            OnConnected(EventArgs.Empty);

        }

    }
```

This is actually an event that is called from a `DeviceWatcher`
The problem is that `targetDevice` is always null.

No crashes no nothing, It's just null, doesn't change.
Why ?

Edit: This is the thing that i have in the manifest:

```
<DeviceCapability Name="usb">
    <Device Id="vidpid:184c 0001">
        <Function Type="classId:ff * *"/>
    </Device>
</DeviceCapability>
```

Comment: Did you [add USB capabilities to the manifest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn303351(v=vs.85).aspx) ?

Comment: `<DeviceCapability Name="usb">
      <Device Id="vidpid:184c 0001">
        <Function Type="classId:ff * *"/>
      </Device>
    </DeviceCapability>`

Not sure if thats correct or not though.

Comment: How to get the classID and such info ?

Comment: I don't know the details either. But do add this to the question, it's relevant. Comments don't count here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just note for memory that it there is null after UsbDevice.FromIdAsync one should check the following:

1. Presence of the device with WinUsb driver in device manager.
2. Presence of multistring parameter DeviceInterfaceGUIDs with generated GUID in registry

   ```
   [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USB\VID_184C&PID_0001\8000013\Device Parameters]
   "DeviceInterfaceGUIDs"=hex(7):7b,00,32,00,34,00,42,00,35,00,37,00,46,00,34,00,\
   37,00,2d,00,41,00,37,00,41,00,43,00,2d,00,34,00,46,00,41,00,32,00,2d,00,39,\
   00,43,00,31,00,33,00,2d,00,32,00,38,00,36,00,42,00,30,00,33,00,34,00,46,00,\
   ```
3. Presence of appropriate DeviceCapability in Package.appxmanifest

   ```
   <Capabilities>
       <DeviceCapability Name="usb">
         <Device Id="vidpid:184C 0001">
           <Function Type="classId:ff * *" />
           <Function Type="name:vendorSpecific" />
         </Device>
       </DeviceCapability>
   ```

Comment: Can you explain "Presence of the device with WinUsb driver in device manager."? How can I do this? Presence in the computer or on the device?

Comment: @Rougher Device should be present in device manager. That means:
* that device is physically connected and 
* WinUsb driver is installed for it.
In this case you will see your device in device manager. "Device manager" is a windows application C:\Windows\System32\devmgmt.msc

Comment: I see it as "USB Component Device" (under Universal Serial Bus Controllers) in Device Manager, BUT UsbDevice.FromIdAsync still returns null...

Comment: @Rougher WinUsb driver should be installed for device first. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/usbcon/winusb-installation

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, the WInUSB driver that Windows installed for me didn't work for some reason, I had to install another one.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41096871/uwp-app-cannot-find-connect-to-usb-device/41098657#41098657 for a winusb custom made driver (I had the same issue, and the custom made driver solved it for me).