# Cannot find usb device iot core

Tags: vb.net, raspberry-pi3, windows-10-iot-core

Trying to connect to my APC UPS via USB and send it raw data.

Package.appxmanifest

```
    <DeviceCapability Name="usb">
  <Device Id="vidpid:051D 0002">
    <Function Type="name:vendorSpecific"/>
  </Device>
</DeviceCapability>
```

StartupTask.vb

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Net.Http
Imports Windows.ApplicationModel.Background

' The Background Application template is documented at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=533884&clcid=0x409

Public NotInheritable Class StartupTask
    Implements IBackgroundTask

        Public Async Sub MainPage_Load(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Loaded
    Dim VID As UInt32 = &H51D
    Dim PID As UInt32 = &H2

    Dim filter As String = Windows.Devices.Usb.UsbDevice.GetDeviceSelector(VID, PID)
    Dim dev As Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformationCollection = Await Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(filter, Nothing)
    If dev.Count > 0 Then
        Dim device As Windows.Devices.Usb.UsbDevice = Await Windows.Devices.Usb.UsbDevice.FromIdAsync(dev(0).Id)
    End If
End Sub
```

Issue is `device` comes up as nothing. `dev.Count` is `1`.

Comment: You may need to [refer to winusb as the driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41096871/uwp-app-cannot-find-connect-to-usb-device).

Comment: Used zadig to replace one of my drivers as a test, and I can see it now. The next step is doing that on my IoT device.

Comment: `devices.First()` now returns a value, but when I go to use `Dim device = Await Windows.Devices.Usb.UsbDevice.FromIdAsync(dev(0).Id)`, I get nothing back.

Comment: Have your code worked on the desktop? If it's not, [Customizing this sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CustomUsbDeviceAccess#customizing-the-sample-for-your-device) for your device and test on the desktop first.

Comment: I've tried but couldn't get it working.