# Find usb device by VID and PID does not work

Tags: c#, uwp, usb

According to this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.usb.usbdevice), I should be able to retrieve the usb device based on Vendor ID and Product ID, it also gives some extra information:

> The vendor and product identifiers for the physical device. Those identifiers are part of the hardware ID string. You can obtain that string from the Models section in the INF file. Alternatively, if WinUSB was loaded based on the compatible ID specified in the device descriptor, you can derive the identifiers from the Hardware Ids property in Device Manager. For example, if Hardware Id is "USB\VID_045E&PID_078E", vendor ID is "0x045E" and product Id is "0x078E".

So I look up the USB Hardware Ids:

[image]

And then I use this code:

```
private async Task<bool> IsDeviceConnected()
{
    uint vid = 0x0529;
    uint pid = 0x0620;
    var deviceSelector = UsbDevice.GetDeviceSelector(vid,pid);
    var allDevices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync();
    var listDevices = allDevices.ToList();
    foreach (var item in listDevices)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"{item.Name} - ID: {item.Id}");
    }
    var deviceCollection = (await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(deviceSelector)).ToList();
    if (deviceCollection.Any())
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The iteration of all devices does provide information about the device I am looking for, slightly different name though:

> Token JC - ID: \?\USB#VID_0529&PID_0620#6&13f4c3e&0&2#{894a7461-a033-11d2-821e-444553540000}
>
> Token JC - ID: \?\USB#VID_0529&PID_0620#6&13f4c3e&0&2#{a6d4c357-c4b7-4dd9-85b7-2bf335618e8e}
>
> Token JC - ID: \?\USB#VID_0529&PID_0620#6&13f4c3e&0&2#{a5dcbf10-6530-11d2-901f-00c04fb951ed}

`deviceSelector` outputs:

> System.Devices.InterfaceClassGuid:="{DEE824EF-729B-4A0E-9C14-B7117D33A817}" AND System.Devices.InterfaceEnabled:=System.StructuredQueryType.Boolean#True AND System.DeviceInterface.WinUsb.UsbVendorId:=1321 AND System.DeviceInterface.WinUsb.UsbProductId:=1568

I have tried also one other device (a microphone) but can't find that either via Vendor ID and product ID. What am I doing wrong?

I have noticed that the GUID that is in the `deviceSelector` query doesn't match with any of the above GUIDs, nor does it match with the "Class Guid" that is listed in the device properties, which is: {36fc9e60-c465-11cf-8056-444553540000}.

Not sure if relevant, but this is within an UWP app environment.

Comment: From this [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41096871/uwp-app-cannot-find-connect-to-usb-device), when he used a custom .inf to refer to winusb as the driver, he could find the USB device. If you try to custom an .inf, can you find the device? About more details, you can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-hardware/drivers/usbcon/winusb-installation).

Comment: I do have the inf file for the device, as this is actually a pre-check to see if both the device is connected and the driver is installed. So using a inf file is at this stage not an option as it might be not installed yet.

Comment: You are using the AQS returned from UsbDevice.GetDeviceSelector(vid,pid). This means you are not looking for any USB device with that VID/PID, but a [WinUSB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/usbcon/winusb) USB device with that VID/PID. If you can’t find their device, then either the VID/PID is wrong, or the device isn’t a WinUSB device. You can can tell whether it’s a WinUSB device by looking at the service property (==WINUSB) for the device in DeviceManager. If it doesn’t, then it’s unlikely to be a WinUSB device (i.e. some other driver is slurping it up).